# Rest v2 report execution success, check status of the report 404 error

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I run `http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions` with the relevant reportExecutionRequest and it returns 200 ok message. The following is the result of the post request.

```
<reportExecution>
<exports>
   <export>
      <id>5eb00aeb-0f42-4195-8aec-b306535c325f</id> 
      <outputResource>
          <contentType>application/pdf</contentType>
          <fileName>ReportTest1.pdf</fileName>
          <outputFinal>false</outputFinal>
      </outputResource>
      <status>ready</status> 
    </export>
</exports>
          <reportURI>/reports/test/ReportTest1</reportURI>
          <requestId>8da22862-35b7-448a-8169-e282d12a02f5</requestId>
          <status>ready</status>
          <totalPages>0</totalPages> 
</reportExecution>
```

But i can't access the report using `http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions/5eb00aeb-0f42-4195-8aec-b306535c325f/status`. Is totalpages 0 is the problem?.

Comment: What would you like us to say? "Yes, total pages 0 may well be the problem"? We don't have enough information.

Answer (score 2):

You put wrong GUID into status check URL. It must come from `<requestId>` element (or `requestId` property in JSON response), not `<id>` in `<export>` block.
So, proper status check address for example is `http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions/8da22862-35b7-448a-8169-e282d12a02f5/status`.

And both calls must be performed with same session cookie, basic authentication will lead to 404 on status check or generated output retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** If totalpages are 0 then there is no report that could be shown to you.

You might want to include a band in your report that is printed every time anyway so a report is generated in any case. That way you would get an empty report instead of nothing.